# Unable to serialize System.Net.Mail.MailAddress to Json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datacontractjsonserializer

I Have a email class as

```
public class EmailInfo
{
    public MailAddress SenderEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public MailAddressCollection ReceiverEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public MailAddressCollection CCEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public MailAddressCollection BCCEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public AttachmentCollection Attachment { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public DateTime EmailDate { get; set; }
}
```

and When I Try to serialize list of Type EmailInfo. I get the the Following error

```
Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Darena.EmailParser.EmailInfo, Darena.EmailParser, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfEmailInfo:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Darena.EmailParser' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
```

I am Serializing using

```
 DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(EmailInfo));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ser.WriteObject(ms, emailInfos);
        string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        ms.Close();
        return jsonString;
```

Any help

Answer (score 0):

The types you want to serialize have to be serializable.

For `DataContractJsonSerializer` it means you have to decorate your class (`EmailInfo`) with `DataContract` attribute and its members (just those you want to include into serialized string) with `DataMember` attribute.

However, in your case you are referencing 3rd party types, like `MailAddress` and other types that are not serializable so you would have to provide some type of custom serialization and its quite limited for `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

Have a look at [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library, which provides much more flexibility for JSON serialization, eg. `JsonConverter`. You'll find good examples at this web site.

Answer (score 0):

The List cannot support the serializetion. You can use the object[] instead of List.